# Loading a script externally

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How do I load a script externally? As in from streaming assets? I would like to make changes to the code. For example a simple code like this

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SetValue: MonoBehaviour
{
    private int value = 12;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

}
```

Comment: _[you don't ....Code is always in the build and its always present, **you can just create a new instance of a class**, be it with addcomponent if it extends from component or its extended classes, or through new XXXX when it inherits from object and alike.   `Resources.Load` is only required for assets.](https://forum.unity.com/threads/how-to-load-a-script-directly-from-resources-folder.75178/)_, Unity Forums

Comment: You can use reflection methods to load an assembly with mono backend, otherwise you need a library like https://github.com/Ourpalm/ILRuntime to execute the script.

Answer (score 1):

Drag the `.cs` file into the project.